# Varnish. how to clean all cache over curl

Tags: caching, curl, varnish

curl command:

```
curl -X PURGE <URL>
```

so it is possible to clear only one page

how to clean the all cache by using `CURL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(varnish 3) I was able to clear the all cache so

```
if (req.request == "BAN") {
 if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
 # Not from an allowed IP? Then die with an error.
 error 405 "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests.";
 }
 ban("req.http.host == " +req.http.host+" && req.url ~ "+req.url);
 error 200 "Ban added";
 }
```

curl -X BAN http://domain.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Add this VCL and then you can use "curl -X BANRE ." to clear the cache.

```
sub vcl_recv {
        if (req.method == "BANRE") {
                # Same ACL check as above:
                if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                        return(synth(403, "Not allowed."));
                }
                ban("req.url ~ " + req.url).
                return(synth(200, "Ban added"));
        }
}
```

Comment: it's probably 4 --- not work the 3 versions, - you can somehow do this on 3 v.?